# Android: Share to Messenger.. unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, android-studio, messenger

I tried to send id of an image from an activity to another activity. But unfortunately stopped. But i couldn't find any solution. This is my main activity. I kept all image id in a class Utils.

```
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",Utils.THUMBNAIL_IDS[position]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And this is my sendActivity from where i tried to share this image to messenger:
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        position=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

Now the code to share to messenger:

```
private void onMessengerButtonClicked() {
        // The URI can reference a file://, content://, or android.resource. Here we use
        // android.resource for sample purposes.

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.amit.bengalistickerfun/drawable/" +
                MainActivity.mAdapter.getItem(position));


        // Create the parameters for what we want to send to Messenger.
        ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
                ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "image/jpeg")
                        .setMetaData("{ \"image\" : \"tree\" }")
                        .build();
// Sharing from an Activity
        MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, 0, shareToMessengerParams);

        if (mPicking) {
            // If we were launched from Messenger, we call MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger to return
            // the content to Messenger.
            MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger(this, shareToMessengerParams);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, we were launched directly (for example, user clicked the launcher icon). We
            // initiate the broadcast flow in Messenger. If Messenger is not installed or Messenger needs
            // to be upgraded, this will direct the user to the play store.
            MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
                    this,
                    REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
                    shareToMessengerParams);
        }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Add your logcat result too.

Comment: without the stacktrace we can´t find the issue. Have You registered SendActivity.class in Your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would suggest to  put try catch block here , so that you can catch the exception. if any
2. try to observe log-cat and view the errors
3. try using android inbuilt logging class to see the logs
4. Post your error logs here ,so that we can see the issue and provide our inputs accordingly.